# Kotlin "Destructuring declaration initializer of type Any must have a 'component1()' function..."

Tags: java, kotlin, destructure

I have a for each loop

```
for(conn in connection) {
   var(first,second,third) = reader.getLatency(conn,LocationAssignment)
}
```

Where reader.getLatency is

```
open class LatencyReader {
    companion object {
        fun getLatency(conn: Connection, locationAssignment: HashMap<String, String>): Any {
            return Triple(LatencyReader.MissingLatency, LatencyReader.MissingLatency, LatencyReader.MissingLatency)

        }

        val MissingLatency: Int = 9999
    }
```

How can I access each element of reader.getLatency(conn,LocationAssignment), most importantly I want to access the last element or the third of the triple.

Comment: Why does `getLatency` return `Any`. It should return `Triple<Int, Int, Int>`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

[Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586965/kotlin-destructuring-declaration-initializer-of-type-any-must-have-a-component/69587013#comment122997907_69586965):

> Why does `getLatency` return `Any`. It should return `Triple<Int, Int, Int>`, shouldn't it?

which was the solution.

Comment: I've edited your answer a bit. Comments can be deleted at any time, so if somebody posts a comment that provides a solution, you can do what I did: link to the user, link to the comment, quote the comment. That way if the comment goes, people still have an answer to your question if they see it.